# Flutter version solving failed while building a cloned repo

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

> Because firebase_auth >=1.4.1 <3.0.0 depends on firebase_core ^1.3.0
> and flash_chat depends on firebase_core ^2.3.0, firebase_auth >=1.4.1
> <3.0.0 is forbidden. So, because flash_chat depends on firebase_auth
> ^2.0.0, version solving failed. Running "flutter pub get" in
> Give-More-master...                         pub get failed (1; So,
> because flash_chat depends on firebase_auth ^2.0.0, version solving
> failed.)

I ran `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, then it brought up the error above. I have also tried changing the plugins but my choice is not working for me.

Comment: Welcome to SO, which error throws to you?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest version from pub.dev

```yaml
   firebase_auth: ^4.1.3
   firebase_core: ^2.3.0
```